# Spring MVC 3 - Respond to request with a 404?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my controller I do a permissions check to see if the user can do the certain action.  If they can't, I'd like to return a 404.

How do I tell Spring to return a 404?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066946/trigger-404-in-spring-mvc-controller

Comment: @axtavt The answer on this page is what I used. Thanks

Comment: You should really respond with a 403..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can throw an exception and handle it in a controller-level method:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @ResponseStatus(NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler({UnauthorizedException.class})
    public void handle() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If any controller method throw a `UnauthorizedException.`, the above handler method will be invoked to handle it and return a 404 error.

Comment: Really slick way of handling this.

Comment: On newer version of Spring, you can just throw NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException in your controller
I comment here because it still appears in google first page

Answer (score -3):

You can derive your exception from HttpException and path 404 code to base constructor:

```
public class MyNotFoundException : HttpException
{
    public MyNotFoundException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(404, message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that's Spring.NET - there's no `HttpException` class in Spring.

Comment: That syntax to call the superclass constructor is C# too.