# Spring sending 401 HTTP response via Controller

Tags: spring, http

Lets say i have a Controller like this one :

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/error")
    public  void getresponse(ModelMap modelMap) {

modelMap.addAttribute("categories", "");
}
```

Is it possible to send a 401 HTTP error when this controller is called? If yes, how ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066946/trigger-404-in-spring-mvc-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its possible. Annotate it with:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
```