# What is the difference between ResponseEntity<T> and @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple handler in my controller which returns a message

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/message")
@ResponseBody
public Message get() {
    return new Message(penguinCounter.incrementAndGet() + " penguin!");
}
```

At the same time I can use something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/message")
ResponseEntity<Message> get() {
    Message message = new Message(penguinCounter.incrementAndGet() + " penguin!");
    return new ResponseEntity<Message>(message, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

What is the difference betweet this two approaches? Let's not take into account HttpStatus :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

ResponseEntity will give you some added flexibility in defining arbitrary HTTP response headers. See the 4th constructor here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

```
ResponseEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers, HttpStatus statusCode)
```

A List of possible HTTP response headers is available here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses

Some commonly-used ones are Status, Content-Type and Cache-Control.

If you don't need that, using @ResponseBody will be a tiny bit more concise.

Comment: What stuff is transmitted in header? Any examples?

Answer (score 7):

**HttpEntity** represents an HTTP **request** or **response** consists of **headers** and **body**.

```
// Only talks about body & headers, but doesn't talk about status code
public HttpEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers)
```

**ResponseEntity** extends HttpEntity but also adds a Http status code.

```
// i.e ResponseEntity = HttpEntity + StatusCode
public ResponseEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers, HttpStatus statusCode)
```

Hence used to **fully** **configure** the HTTP response.

For Ex:

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class JavaWebExeptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    ExceptionErrorCodeMap exceptionErrorCodeMap;

    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponseBody> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex) {
        Integer expCode = exceptionErrorCodeMap.getExpCode(ex.getClass());
        // We have not added headers to response here, If you want you can add by using respective constructor
        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponseBody>(new ExceptionResponseBody(expCode, ex.getMessage()),
                HttpStatus.valueOf(expCode));
    }

}
```

**@ResponseBody** indicates that **return** value of **method** on which it is used is bound to the response **body** 
(Mean the return value of method is treated as Http response body)

Answer (score 3):

**ResponseEntity<>** is a generic class with a type parameter, you can specify what type of object to be serialized into the response body.

**@ResponseBody** is an annotation, indicates that the return value of a method will be serialized into the body of the HTTP response.

you can set headers using **ResponseEntity<>**

Answer (score -1):

**@ResponseEntity** represents a response which includes headers, body and status code.
**@ResponseBody** only returns the body of the response.

Comment: You confused me, I thought there was a `@ResponseEntity` annotation.