# How do i hide JSON fields for an object in spring

Tags: json, spring

I have an object in spring in which i would like to hide fields while using `@` responsebody and display the fields back when i want to return using `@responseentity`.

I tried `@jsonignore` on setter and `@jsonproperty` on getter... it doesn't work...

I tried `@jsonproperty(access=Read.only)` On fields i wanted to hide...it doesn't  work...

I tried `@jsonignoreproperties` ... it doesn't work

Is there a way to do it...rather than creating 2 objects

Please help... thanks

Comment: Not sure you can do it solely with those annotations, but  for what it's worth you can do the opposite(exclude a property from deserialization) as detailed in http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/21/jackson-using-jsonignore-and-jsonproperty-annotations-to-exclude-a-property-only-from-json-deserialization/

Answer (score 0):

You cant Hide fields in the object by using @responsebody and display it by using @responseentity.

If you want to send any additional data using HTTPResponse headers then we can use @Responseentity. Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725143/what-is-the-difference-between-responseentityt-and-responsebody) to see the difference between these 2 annotations.

To actually answer your question we can create custom annotation and use it in controller to hide fields in the response. Refer [this](https://github.com/galleog/sandbox/tree/master/jsonfilter) Github project for implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom serializer and use it directly with ObjectMapper or apply it to the class using @JsonSerialize, short tutorial: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization