# Add a body to a 404 Not Found Exception

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jhipster

In an REST API generated with JHipster, I want to throw some 404 exceptions. It is normally done with

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

which actualy results in a 404 response to the xhr request. The problem is that in the front side, JHipster parses the response with

```
angular.fromJson(result)
```

and such result is empty when the 404 is the actual response, which makes the parse to fail.

If I point to an unmapped URI, lets say `/api/user` while my controller maps to `/api/users` (note the plural) the 404 I got from the API has a body in it:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2016-04-25T18:33:19.947+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/user/myuser/contact"
}
```

which is correctly parse in angular.

How can I create a body like this? Is this exception thrown by spring or is tomcat who throws it?

I tried this: [Trigger 404 in Spring-MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066946/trigger-404-in-spring-mvc-controller) but I cant set the parameters of the response.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Basic Idea

---

First option is to define error objects and return them as `404 Not Found` body. Something like following:

```
Map<String, String> errors = ....;
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(errors);
```

Instead of returning a typical `ResponseEntity`, you can throw an `Exception` that will be resolved to a `404 Not Found`. Suppose you have a `NotFoundException` like:

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {}
```

Then if you throw this exception in your controllers, you would see something like:

```
{  
   "timestamp":1461621047967,
   "status":404,
   "error":"Not Found",
   "exception":"NotFoundException",
   "message":"No message available",
   "path":"/greet"
}
```

If you want to customize the message and other parts of body, you should define a `ExceptionHandler` for `NotFoundException`.

## Introducing Exception Hierarchies

---

If you're creating a RESTful API and want to have different *Error Codes* and *Error Messages* for different exceptional cases, you can create a hierarchy of exceptions representing those cases and extract message and code from each one.

For example, you can introduce an exception, say, `APIException` which is super-class of all other exceptions thrown by your controllers. This class defines a code/message pair like:

```
public class APIException extends RuntimeException {
    private final int code;
    private final String message;

    APIException(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int code() {
        return code;
    }

    public String message() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Each subclass depending on the nature of its exception can provide some sensible values for this pair. For example, we could have an `InvalidStateException`:

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class InvalidStateException extends APIException {
    public InvalidStateException() {
        super(1, "Application is in invalid state");
    }
}
```

Or that notorious not found ones:

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class SomethingNotFoundException extends APIException {
    public SomethingNotFoundException() {
        super(2, "Couldn't find something!");
    }
}
```

Then we should define an `ErrorController` that catches those exceptions and turn them to meaningful JSON representations. That error controller may look like following:

```
@RestController
public class APIExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorController {
    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";
    private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @Autowired
    public APIExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        super(errorAttributes);
        this.errorAttributes = errorAttributes;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = ERROR_PATH)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);

        Map<String, Object> errors = getErrorAttributes(request, false);
        getApiException(request).ifPresent(apiError -> {
            errors.put("message" , apiError.message());
            errors.put("code", apiError.code());
        });
        // If you don't want to expose exception!
        errors.remove("exception");


        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(errors);
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }

    private Optional<APIException> getApiException(HttpServletRequest request) {
        RequestAttributes attributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
        Throwable throwable = errorAttributes.getError(attributes);
        if (throwable instanceof APIException) {
            APIException exception = (APIException) throwable;
            return Optional.of(exception);
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

So, if you throw an `SomethingNotFoundException`, the returned JSON would be like:

```
{  
   "timestamp":1461621047967,
   "status":404,
   "error":"Not Found",
   "message":"Couldn't find something!",
   "code": 2,
   "path":"/greet"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, but this way I can't define the message. I tried adding the reason property as in @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Resource not found") but then the response is something like {"message":"error.404","description":"Resource not found","fieldErrors":null}

Comment: By the way I throw it this way return Optional.ofNullable(entity)
            .map(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(
                result,
                HttpStatus.OK))
            .orElseThrow(HTTPNotFoundException::new);

Comment: Do you know if I can easily log all exceptions that are mapped using `@ResponseStatus`?

Comment: This code doesn't work: errorAttributes.getError expected WebRequest not  RequestAttributes

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do this if you want to return some message or test with your error code

```
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity somthing() {
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
return new ResponseEntity<>(new Gson().toJson("hello this is my message"), headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "message");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).